Как прикрепить фото к сообщению, как предпросмотр ссылки, после последнего обновления Telegraph
В связи с недавним обновлением Telegram, на сайт Telegraph теперь нельзя загружать медиафайлы, можно только вставлять ссылку на них. И в этом, собственно говоря, заключается моя проблема.
У меня два бота построены на функции, которая загружала отправленные пользователем фотографии на Telegraph, а возвращала эта функция ссылку на данное фото и прикрепляла его, как предпросмотр ссылки, к сообщению. И вот теперь, из-за данного обновления, мои два бота не могут полноценно функционировать. Для сохранения фотографий на сервере и их отправки потом вместе с текстом у меня  нет ни ресурсов, ибо сервер не позволит справиться с таким объемом информации, ни смысла, потому что большинство постов по количеству символов выходят за допустимые пределы Telegram.
Может Вы, более опытные коллеги, посоветуете способ, как можно решить данную проблему, чтобы всё-таки публикации отправлялись предпросмотром? Возможно, есть какие то аналоги Telegraph, которые можно будет использовать похожим образом? Или, возможно, всё таки есть способ как-то загрузить публикацию на сам Telegraph, и получить назад ссылку на медиа-ресурс?

Просто поднимите локальный сервер например на FastAPI или Flask и сделайте фунцию, которая по эндпойнту.
Например
/file/{file_name}
будет возвращать вам фотку с сервера (фотка должна будет храниться локально), а тг сам будет делать предпросмотр.
Если сразу не получится, то нужно будет поиграться с мета-тегами еще
